# Add multiple numeric string values in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework code first and pulling some data back from our database.  In the table I'm accessing is 13 columns that store the number of a items a customer purchased per week for the last 13 weeks as a char field.  I have no control over how this data is stored.  I need to total the 13 weeks results together to get a combined total, so take week1 + week2 + week3.... = Total Items Purchased over 13 weeks.

In SQL I'd just Cast the char to an Integer and add the values together.  But I'm struggling finding a solution to do this in linq.

I tried

```
(From c in Table
Select New With {.Usage = (Convert.ToInt32(c.week1) + 
                           Convert.ToInt32(c.week2) + etc)}).ToList()
```

as well trying to use Integer.Parse instead of Convert.ToInt32.

If you have anything that could help me out I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try the code you've got, or Integer.Parse?

Comment: you want to add all fields for an item, and require list of all additions right. (similar to Row to column in DB, then Sum())

Comment: The error I'm getting is LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF can't translate Convert.Int32 (and a lot of other LINQ statements...) into SQL. You should just peform the query normally using LINQ to Entities and then perform the conversion outside LINQ.

Comment: I figured this might be the solution but was hoping there was something out there that I'd missed for converting.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've had the same issue and never found any clean solution, you can use TSQL CAST and execute this manually against the database from EF but I prefer to keep an all code solution.